# Drop-down functionality in xcode 4.2

Tags: ios, xcode

I have upgraded my xcode version from 3.2.6 to 4.2 .

Is drop-down functionality inbuilt in xcode 4.2 so that i can directly drag and drop it on

interface builder and feed values to it .

Thanks .

Comment: You can use Picker as an option for drop down. There are two pickers available. One is UIDatePicker and other is UIPicker. This link may help you get started. http://www.iphonesdkarticles.com/2009/01/uipickerview-creating-simple-picker.html

Comment: WHat do you mean by drop-down functionality? Also interface builder is  now part of Xcode and not separate

Answer (score 1):

Followings are steps to drag the variable on xcode 4.2

1.select the editor mode of the xcode

[image: 1.select the editor mode of the xcode]

2.select the files to which the change aries like .xib file and .h file
[image]

3.Now drag the button and put into xib file

[image]

4.Right click on button and select new refrence.
[image]

5.Drag and select the name of the variable here.
[image]

6.Enter the name of the variable here.
[image]

7.It show below optput like this

[image]

It may be helping to learn new funcationality.
Happy codeing
@neon samuel